# How would I append the result value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getNote() {
var textField = document.getElementById('textField').value;
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = textField; 
} 
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
submitButton.addEventListener('click',getNote);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">NoteTaker</a>
 
</div>
<title>Note Taker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body id="style">
<div id ="centerField">
<h1> New Note</h1>
<textarea  id="textField"rows="8" cols="70%"  placeholder ="Type Here."></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">Submit Information</button>
</div>
<div id ="leftField" >
 <h2> Saved Notes</h2>
 <p id='result'></p></div>
 <div id="container"></div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want every value to keep being added to the field. So when I submit Test and then submit Help the field should have both. Right now it adds then replace and now im stumped.

Comment: result.innerHTML += textField

Comment: I think one of these answers could be the solution. You could accept an answer that is citing a possibly acceptable solution. This closes the loop.

Comment: @Sidtharthan Sounds like you are fishing for an acceptance of your answer.

Comment: I think '@ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ' answer is correct. I am wanting to know whether it is meeting the questioner's requirement.

Comment: '@Carsten Løvbo Andersen' I did not answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to ovveride it and keep append, take the old value and and add the new value to it.

```
result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + " " + textField;
```

---

```js
function getNote() {
var textField = document.getElementById('textField').value;
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = result.innerHTML + " " + textField; 
} 
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
submitButton.addEventListener('click',getNote);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">NoteTaker</a>
 
</div>
<title>Note Taker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body id="style">
<div id ="centerField">
<h1> New Note</h1>
<textarea  id="textField"rows="8" cols="70%"  placeholder ="Type Here."></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">Submit Information</button>
</div>
<div id ="leftField" >
 <h2> Saved Notes</h2>
 <p id='result'></p></div>
 <div id="container"></div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#submitButton").on("click", function(){
 $("p#result").append($("#textField").val() + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Note Taker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body id="style">
  <div id="centerField">
    <h1> New Note</h1>
    <textarea id="textField" rows="8" cols="70%" placeholder="Type Here."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">
    Submit Information
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="leftField">
    <h2> Saved Notes</h2>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/spf0bt71/1/

```js
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
 var textField = $('#textField').val();
  $('#result').append(textField, '<br/>'); 
  $('#textField').val('');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="centerField">
  <h1> New Note</h1>
  <textarea  id="textField"rows="8" cols="70%"  placeholder ="Type Here."></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">Submit Information</button>
</div>
<div id ="leftField" >
  <h2> Saved Notes</h2>
   <p id='result'></p>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: hey im still learning but the solution works perfectly in fiddle but when I try it my self... Using code been it does not work

Comment: Please check the browser console for errors... and please provide the error details, will try to solve it together...

Comment: thanks for the support but I was able to get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
  $('#result').append($('#textField').val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="centerField">
  <h1> New Note</h1>
  <textarea  id="textField"rows="8" cols="70%"  placeholder ="Type Here."></textarea>
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">Submit Information</button>
</div>
<div id ="leftField" >
  <h2> Saved Notes</h2>
   <p id='result'></p>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element. that's why every time textField value will be append to the result. 
.appendTo() can be used instead of .append()